# Sql group by without sum function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table called `Products` like this:

```
    date       | product | amount | gross
1-) 10/03/2020 | TV      | 300    | 500  
2-) 10/03/2020 | Table   | 200    | 400
3-) 10/03/2020 | Phone   | 100    | 200
4-) 10/02/2020 | Table   | 40     | 215
5-) 10/02/2020 | Phone   | 35     | 100
6-) 10/01/2020 | Tv      | 145    | 420
7-) 10/12/2019 | Table   | 400    | 800
8-) 10/12/2019 | Tv      | 200    | 450
```

What I want to do is to group the table according to date and to write products and amounts another columns

Result table should be like this:

```
        date   |product1|amount1|gross1|product2|amount2| gross2|product3|amount3 |gross3

1-) 10/03/2020 | TV     | 300   | 500  |Table   |200    |400    |Phone   |100     |200 
2-) 10/02/2020 | Table  |  40   | 215  |Phone   |35     |100    |null    |null    |null
3-) 10/01/2020 | Tv     | 145   | 420  |null    |null   |null   |null    |null    |null
4-) 10/12/2019 | Table  | 400   | 800  |Tv      |200    |450    |null    |null    |null
```

I tried to use group by but it is not working because I do not need sum funciton for amounts.Do you have any idea what can I do.?

```
select 
    date, product1, amount1, gross1,
    product2, amount2, gross2,
    product3, amount3, gross3 
from
    Products 
group by 
    date
```

Comment: try PIVOT : https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed count of products per day, you can use conditional aggregation - but you need a column that defines the ordering of rows having the same date, I assumed `id`:

```
select date,
    max(case when rn = 1 then product end) as product1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then amount  end) as amount1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then gross   end) as gross1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then product end) as product2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then amount  end) as amount2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then gross   end) as gross2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then product end) as product3,
    max(case when rn = 3 then amount  end) as amount3,
    max(case when rn = 3 then gross   end) as gross3
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by date order by id) as rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by date
order by date desc
```

Comment: where should do I define id column?You mean  that I should add id column also Products table.Am i right?

Comment: @erhan: I mean that you need to decide which column you want to use to order the records. There is nothing obvious in your data that indicates what it should be, so I used an hypothetical column called `id`. You can replace that with an actual column of your table.

Comment: Thank you very much.I understood you and it is working